# ref does not work in this reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the css class of a `span` element whenever an anchor  is clicked

I will modify the css class in the onclick callback

```
class Button extends Component {
  handleCallback() {
    this.icon.className = this.icon.className + ' wiggle'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className='highlight'>{this.props.summary}</span>
        <a  
          className='link'
          onClick={this.handleCallback}
        >   
          <span ref={(c) => this.icon = c} className='icon-up'></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

To do so I need to be able to refer the component. That's why I use the `ref` attribute in the span class.

However when the callback is called, I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of null
```

Why the `ref` does not work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a few things here

First off, you're writing an ES6 component class and when using ES6 together with React, React no longer features auto binding of `this` making your call to `handleCallback` refer to a `this` which will be null.

`this.handleCallback.bind(this)` or declare your callback with an arrow function `handleCallback = () => {}` will take care of that problem.

And secondly, the way you're trying to set the className is not allowed, React only updates the tree (i.e., what you see) when re-rendering and React will never flush the changes you made 'inline' back into the DOM so you would have to utilize `this.setState()` or `this.forceUpdate()` in order to be able to see, but since your changes are inline they will never persist on a subsequent render.

Below is a very verbose Component to illustrate how to do it

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      shouldWiggle: false
    };
  }
  handleCallback() {
    this.setState({shouldWiggle: !this.state.shouldWiggle});
  }
  render() {
    let cls = this.state.shouldWiggle ? 'icon-up wiggle': 'icon-up';
    return (
      <div>
        <span className='highlight'>{this.props.summary}</span>
        <a  
          className='link'
          onClick={this.handleCallback.bind(this)}
        >   
          <span ref={(c) => this.icon = c} className={cls}>ad</span>
        </a>

      </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for `this.handleCallback.bind(this)`. I spent a day figuring out this until I come here.